# Handler does not work reliably in Android

Tags: android, service, handler

I have programmed an app which uses a handler. Inside the handler there are some network operations.
The handler has an interval of min*1000*60 ms. I used the handler with min=5, so it should repeat after five minutes. But this is the result of my check:

First Handler:

```
16:20:22
16:25:23
17:01:52
17:13:07
17:20:19
17:25:55
```

Second Handler:

```
16:20:26
16:25:26
17:01:35
17:12:51
17:20:02
17:25:37
```

Third Handler:

```
16:24:58
16:31:59
17:12:43
17:19:54
17:25:30
```

All Handlers are running in separate Services. The screen is turned off.
Do you have any ideas or alternatives to a Handler in Android?

The code of the handlers is so simple:

```
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
            // network operations
            }
        }, interval);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, assuming that you created your `Handler` via `new Handler()`, it will do its work on the main application thread. **Do not do network I/O on the main application thread**. It also is likely the source of your drift.

Second, most likely you do not need three services. Usually, you need one service. Three services simply makes your app more complicated for no added value to the user.

Third, your `Handler` will only work while the device is awake, and I do not know whether that is an acceptable limitation or not.

Fourth, using a `Handler` implies that your service(s) will be running indefinitely, and users do not like this. **Only have your services be in memory when they are actively delivering value to the user**.

A better way to implement this, therefore, is to use `AlarmManager` for your scheduled events. If you do not need the events to be processed while the device is asleep, the `AlarmManager` can directly pass control to your service. Ideally, that would be an `IntentService`, so that the service will give you a background thread automatically and so that the service will automatically shut itself down when the work is complete.

If you need the events to be processed even while the device is asleep, please give the user control over the event period, including an option of "do not do anything", as waking up the device every 5 minutes to do network I/O will be bad for the battery. Then, use [a `WakefulBroadcastReceiver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver.html) or [a `WakefulIntentService`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful) to arrange to have your work be done while keeping the device awake.

Comment: 1. The network Thread is not running in the main Thread. It would crash the App. 2. I need three Handlers because they are not running in the same interval. 3. Thank you for this information. I will try out AlarmManager.

Comment: @JavaForAndroid: "2. I need three Handlers because they are not running in the same interval." -- not according to your question, which says they are running the same interval (5 minutes).

Comment: The interval is the same. But there is a small difference (5000ms), because the app uses some features of the device. Btw: What do you think about CountDownTime? This seems to be an alternative.

Comment: @JavaForAndroid: Since `CountDownTimer` uses a `Handler` internally, and one that is tied to the main application thread, it suffers from all of the problems that I outlined in my answer.

Comment: AlarmManager works fine. Thank you so much.especially for your explaination.

Answer (score 0):

Use `SheduledThreadPoolExecutor` instead of handler.
It has `scheduleAtFixedRate` function, which does exactly what you need. And no handlers at all)

Comment: This still requires the service to run indefinitely, which is unrealistic. It also does not address any potential issues with needing this work to be done when the device is otherwise asleep.